# Prisma not working after Electron app packaging

Tags: sqlite, electron, prisma

I have been working on application using electron.js, react, prisma, sqlite3
I have used this boilerplate as a start for my project

[Electron React Boilerplate](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/)

The app works well in development mode, but when I packed the app to be executable program, It doesn't work.
I have searched a lot and figured out that the problem is because of prisma
I found this [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9613) on github that have a solution in this [comment](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9613#issuecomment-970743002)
But I don't understand how to use it in my project.

Does anyone know how to make this solution work in my project, or any other valid solution ?